# Java binary file to share with another computer

Tags: java, binaryfiles

How do I write to a pre-specified binary file format in Java that I can share with another computer that will parse it (and other computer is not using Java)? The file format has longs, floats, and some bitfields. This is a file that the Java program will write data to and then share with another computer. Is there a better way to do this than with a binary file format?

Comment: So you want something precompiled and written in java but running on a computer that doesn't have java?

Comment: There _are_ some ahead-of-time compilers for Java.  Don't know whether any of them are any good or still maintained.

Comment: Are you trying to make a Java executable or a data file that is binary data instead of ASCII characters?

Comment: he is trying to find a binary file format which can be written by Java and then parsed w/o Java (so to say using Java serialization is not a good fit for him)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't have to be binary you can use XML or JSON.  If it has to be binary, use [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).

Comment: Yes, Protocol Buffers may work, but will I have to use the Protocol Buffer API to read the file too? I have pre-existing code written in PHP that parses my specific file format. It would be nice if I didn't have to rewrite any of that code.

Comment: Protocol buffers have apis for everything.  Re 2nd part of your comment -- please consider writing better questions, nobody wants to beg you to disclose enough information about your question so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be binary, I would use ByteBuffer which support reading/write primitive in any combination and with any byte order (endianess)  You can create wrappers so when you read/write it can appear as events, messages or event types (so you hide the fact you are dealing with a binary file)